# How to make sub links appear when mouse upon a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have placed my code in http://jsfiddle.net/ChvjL/4/

While the mouse pointer is upon Link1 then the sub links link1a, link1b, link1c should appear.

Similarly for Link2 also.

Can anyone help me in resolving this

Thanks in advance
Amith

Comment: You have invalid html in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea how it should be in your case:

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="USEPCreate.html">Link1a</a></li>
            <li><a href="USEPUpdate.html">Link1b</a></li>
            <li><a href="USEPRecovery.html">Link1c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="USEPCreate.html">Link2a</a></li>
            <li><a href="USEPUpdate.html">Link2b</a></li>
            <li><a href="USEPRecovery.html">Link2c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul > li { width:100px; float:left; }
ul > li > ul { display:none; }
ul > li:hover > ul { display:block; }
ul > li > ul { padding-left:10px; }
```

Code http://jsfiddle.net/ChvjL/10/

Comment: Its working. But can u pls this code http://jsfiddle.net/ChvjL/13/

While the mouse is pointing the link the row itself is getting extended

Comment: This works fine. But the sublinks are not appearing as a sub link. i.e; Create, update and recovery should come as a submenu of Loan & Subsidy. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean that it looks like not sublinks? If you need you can ajust your css. Tell me what you want to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that when a person hovers at the link given, another link will be shown?

You can refer to this example. It's similar. You just need change the content:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).